# Question about a theorem of Littlewood

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm reading the book "The Theory of Functions" by E.C. Titchmarsh. He shows the proof of a theorem of Littlewood (Titchmarsh refers to: J.E. Littlewood, "On the zeros of the Riemann zeta-function", *Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc. 22* (1924), 295-318). In its simplest form, the theorem states that the contour integral of $log (z-w)$ around a rectangle with sides $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, $y_2$ (with $x_1<x_2$ and $y_1<y_2$), where $w=\alpha+i\beta$ lies within the rectangle, equals $2\pi i(x_1-\alpha)$. What I don't understand is why the result does not depend on $x_2$, $y_1$, $y_2$ or $\beta$. Could someone explain that to me, please?

Answer (score 1):

The Littlewood theorem you are referring to is a variant of Cauchy's integral theorem, which states that the contour integral of a holomorphic function around a closed path is zero, as long as the function is holomorphic in the region enclosed by the path.

In this case, we are taking the contour integral of $log(z-w)$ around a rectangle with sides $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, $y_2$. The function $log(z-w)$ is holomorphic in the region enclosed by the rectangle, as long as $w=\alpha+i\beta$ lies within the rectangle.

The complex logarithm function is defined as $log(z) = log|z| + iArg(z)$, where $Arg(z)$ is the argument of $z$, which is the angle between the positive real axis and the vector pointing to $z$. It also important to note that in the case of the Littlewood theorem, the logarithm is not considered as a multi-valued function, it's a single-valued function. The integration is done around a rectangle and the logarithm function is defined on this rectangle. It's defined as $log(z-w) = log(z-\alpha-i\beta) = log(|z-\alpha-i\beta|)+iArg(z-\alpha-i\beta)$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are fixed numbers, so it's not a multi-valued function anymore, it's single-valued.

When we integrate this function over the rectangle, we are summing over all possible values of the function, which means that the integral is independent of the specific values of $x_2$, $y_1$, $y_2$, and $\beta$, because they only affect the value of the argument of $z$, and the integral is over the whole range of the argument.

So, the result only depends on the value of $\alpha$ which is the real part of the point $w$ and the value of $x_1$ which is the lower limit of the contour integral, and the integral of the logarithm function around the rectangle with these value is $2\pi i (x_1-\alpha)$.

Comment: To add to this informative answer, note that one can change how one defines the logarithm eg by going from the bottom edge to the top on vertical segments and then the answer accordingly changes to depend on the top edge only and of course one can go right to left etc; this way is specifically done by Littlewood because the RZ function is nice to the right of $1$ so we know its logarithm exists there and then we can continue it on horizontal segments to the left and get results

Comment: Thanks for your answers! So you can't use the same definition for the logarithm when you go f.e. from right to left? Titchmarsh says "we start with a particular determination on $x=x_2$". What does that mean? The principal value?

Comment: No it means that we are given a continuous logarithm on the right edge of the boundary which exists since by hypothesis $f$ is non zero on the boundary so in particular we can pick a continuous logarithm on a segment from it; it's a good exercise to pick a rectangle and a point $w$ inside and apply Littlewood procedure to $z-w$ where you start on each edge at a time and go with segments towards the opposite edge and see how the (explicit) answer changes depending on which edge you start

Comment: Take the function $z\mapsto e^{iz}$ and try to invert it. You will discover that this is only possible if you restrict the domain, and that there are infinitely many ways to do this. The procedure you find in this way will lead you to the definition of the logarithm(s).

Comment: @Conrad: Could you give an example of "a continuous logarithm" on the right edge of the boundary an one on the left edge, for the function $log(z)$, on a rectangle with $x_2$ unequal to $x_1$? According to Littlewood's theorem the contour integral of $log(z)$ around a rectangle can have different outcomes, depending on how the logarithm is defined. What I don't understand is how exactly the definition of the logarithm causes this. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Take $z=0$ and $x_1=1, x_2=-2$ between $\pm 1$ say; then starting on the right edge the argument starts at $-\pi/4$ goes to $\pi/4$ and following continuation right to left on the top left edge we go from some $\theta$ in the 3rd quadrant to $\pi$ above the real axis and from $-\theta$ to $-\pi$ below; if we start on the left edge the argument goes from some $\alpha$ in $[\pi, 2\pi]$ say to $\pi$ to $2\pi -\theta$ and the continuing left to right we go to the right hand side having argument $\beta$ to $0$ above real axis and $2\pi-\beta$ to $2\pi$ below, so very different

Comment: So in other words if we start from the right and go to left we have a $2\pi$ jump in the argument at $-2$, while if we go the other way we have a $2\pi$ jump at $1$ - you can parametrize and integrate with say Wolfram alpha (all integrals of import are of $\arctan y, \arctan y/2$ but the bounds (and of course what arctangent we take in terms of branch) from first case and second case change and the difference will account for getting $2 \times 2\pi i$ vs $-1 \times 2\pi i$; using Cauchy with a cut as in Titchmarsh is easier but less explicit

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you for your thorough explanation!